# Different performance of object with same runtime class but different static type

Tags: scala, performance, scala-collections

Consider the following jmh benchmark

```
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
@BenchmarkMode(Array(Mode.Throughput))
class So59893913 {
  def seq(xs: Seq[Int]) = xs.sum
  def range(xs: Range) = xs.sum

  val xs = 1 until 100000000
  @Benchmark def _seq = seq(xs)
  @Benchmark def _range = range(xs)
}
```

Given `xs` references the same object of runtime class `Range.Inclusive` passed in as argument to `seq` and `range` methods, hence dynamic dispatch should invoke the same implementation of `sum`, despite differing declared static type of method parameter, why the performance seems to differ so drastically as indicated below?

`sbt "jmh:run -i 10 -wi 5 -f 2 -t 1 -prof gc bench.So59893913"`

```
[info] Benchmark                                          Mode  Cnt          Score          Error   Units
[info] So59893913._range                                 thrpt   20  334923591.408 ± 22126865.963   ops/s
[info] So59893913._range:·gc.alloc.rate                  thrpt   20         ≈ 10⁻⁴                 MB/sec
[info] So59893913._range:·gc.alloc.rate.norm             thrpt   20         ≈ 10⁻⁷                   B/op
[info] So59893913._range:·gc.count                       thrpt   20            ≈ 0                 counts
[info] So59893913._seq                                   thrpt   20  193509091.399 ±  2347303.746   ops/s
[info] So59893913._seq:·gc.alloc.rate                    thrpt   20       2811.311 ±       34.142  MB/sec
[info] So59893913._seq:·gc.alloc.rate.norm               thrpt   20         16.000 ±        0.001    B/op
[info] So59893913._seq:·gc.churn.PS_Eden_Space           thrpt   20       2811.954 ±       33.656  MB/sec
[info] So59893913._seq:·gc.churn.PS_Eden_Space.norm      thrpt   20         16.004 ±        0.035    B/op
[info] So59893913._seq:·gc.churn.PS_Survivor_Space       thrpt   20          0.013 ±        0.005  MB/sec
[info] So59893913._seq:·gc.churn.PS_Survivor_Space.norm  thrpt   20         ≈ 10⁻⁴                   B/op
[info] So59893913._seq:·gc.count                         thrpt   20       3729.000                 counts
[info] So59893913._seq:·gc.time                          thrpt   20       1864.000                     ms
```

Particularly notice the difference in `gc.alloc.rate` metrics.

Comment: Which Scala version is this?

Comment: `scalaVersion := "2.13.1"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things are going on.

The first is that when `xs` has the static type `Range` then that call to `sum` is a monomorphic method call (because `sum` is final in `Range`) and the JVM can easily inline that method and optimize it further. When `xs` has the static type `Seq` then it becomes a megamorphic method call which won't get inlined and fully optimized.

The second is that the methods that get called are *not actually the same*. The compiler generates **two** `sum` methods in `Range`:

```
scala> :javap -p scala.collection.immutable.Range
Compiled from "Range.scala"
public abstract class scala.collection.immutable.Range extends scala.collection.immutable.AbstractSeq<java.lang.Object> implements scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq<java.lang.Object>, scala.collection.immutable.StrictOptimizedSeqOps<java.lang.Object, scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq, scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq<java.lang.Object>>, java.io.Serializable {
...
public final <B> int sum(scala.math.Numeric<B>);
...
public final java.lang.Object sum(scala.math.Numeric);
...
}
```

The first one contains the actual implementation that you see in the source code. And as you can see it returns an unboxed `int`. The second one is this:

```
  public final java.lang.Object sum(scala.math.Numeric);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: aload_1
       2: invokevirtual #898                // Method sum:(Lscala/math/Numeric;)I
       5: invokestatic  #893                // Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
       8: areturn
```

As you see this one just calls the other `sum` method and boxes the `int` into a `java.lang.Integer`.

So in your method `seq` the compiler only knows about the existence of the `sum` method that has return type `java.lang.Object` and calls that one. It probably doesn't get inlined and the `java.lang.Integer` that it returns has to be unboxed again so `seq` can return an `int`. In `range` the compiler can generate a call to the "real" `sum` method without having to box and unbox the results. The JVM can also do a better job at inlining and optimizing the code.